# Google sheets onedit method causes script to crash that would otherwise work?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two google sheets files. I want to have a checkbox in a second sheet be set to true if I check a checkbox in the first sheet document. I have the following code distilled down to the basic procedure.

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 1 && activeCell.getRow() == 2){ 
    myFunction() 
  }

}
function myFunction() {
       var ss_target =SpreadsheetApp.openById('####ID####');
       var Sheet = ss_target.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
       Sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue(true);

}
```

For some reason the code stops at the following line:
 `var ss_target =SpreadsheetApp.openById('####ID####');`

The interesting thing is if I draw a box in google sheets and assign myFunction() to that box when I click on the box the code works perfectly. its only when I try to run the code with the onedit trigger. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make this an installable trigger because simple triggers cannot perform functions that require permission.  Like changing user data.

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast('Entry');
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=='Sheet2' && e.range.columnStart==1 && e.range.rowStart==2){ 
    SpreadsheetApp.openById('tssid').getSheetByName('Sheet2').getRange('A1').setValue("TRUE");
  }
}

function makeTrigger() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onMyEdit').forSpreadsheet(ss.getId()).onEdit().create()
}
```

Comment: Same thing if I use the above code with the following edit SpreadsheetApp.openById('tssid').getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(1, 1).setValue(true);  it will work if I set a image to call a function but not in the onEdit event

Comment: It's a permissions issue.

Comment: You need to create installable trigger.  You can do it in code or via your edit menu.